# How to append alpha values inside nested list in python?

Tags: python

How to append alpha  values inside nested list in python?

```
nested_list = [['72010', 'PHARMACY', '-IV', 'FLUIDS', '7.95'], ['TOTAL', 
'HOSPITAL', 'CHARGES', '6,720.92'],['PJ72010', 'WORD',  'FLUIDS', 
'7.95']]



Expected_output:
[['72010', 'PHARMACY -IV FLUIDS', '7.95'], ['TOTAL HOSPITAL CHARGES', '6,720.92'],['PJ72010', 'WORD  FLUIDS', '7.95']]
```

Comment: Are the sublists always that way?

Comment: What?  You want to combine sublists?  How, When, Why?

Comment: i want to combine the string

Comment: You want to combine THE string?  Which string?  They are quite a few.

Comment: strings between number and  float

Comment: All the elements are strings.

Comment: alpha values i want to extract

Comment: What is an "alpha value"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create a function that defines what you mean by word you can use [`itertools.groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group by this function. Then you can either append the `join()`ed results or `extend()` depending on whether it's a group of numbers of word.

I'm inferring from your example that you are defining words from as anything with no numbers, but you can adjust the function as you see fit:

```
from itertools import groupby

# it's a word if it has no numerics
def word(s):
    return not any(c.isnumeric() for c in s)

def groupwords(s):
    sub = []
    for isword, v in groupby(s, key = word):
        if isword:
            sub.append(" ".join(v))
        else:
            sub.extend(v)
    return sub

res =[groupwords(l) for l in nested_list]
res
```

**Results:**

```
[['72010', 'PHARMACY -IV FLUIDS', '7.95'],
 ['TOTAL HOSPITAL CHARGES', '6,720.92'],
 ['PJ72010', 'WORD FLUIDS', '7.95']]
```

Comment: Mark, I down voted you.  Any answer which states: I'm guessing...  Implies the question needs work.  Get the question fixed then answer it.  You may have gotten the OP what they need, but you did not provide any value beyond that.  The question is quite unclear.

Comment: Thanks @StephenRauch I appreciate that. I actually thought the example made the intention quite clear especially since it included `PJ72010` as a non-grouped item. But because of the ambiguity I made the decision of what is or is not a word an easy-to-change function. Regardless, I appreciate the feedback — thanks.

Comment: So, edit the question. You have been here a while.  If the question made sense to you, then edit it to make sense to more people.  We have badges for that: [refiner](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4369/refiner) and [illuminator](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4370/illuminator).  Take your obviously high level of knowledge and help make it more applicable to more people.  Thanks and cheers.

Comment: `join` and `extend` can accept iterator, no need `list(v)` first

Answer (score 0):

Go through the each nested list. Check the each element of that list . If it is a full alpha den append it in a temporary variable. Once you find a numeric append the temporary and numeric both.
Code:

```
nested_list = [['72010', 'PHARMACY', '-IV', 'FLUIDS', '7.95'], ['TOTAL', 
'HOSPITAL', 'CHARGES', '6,720.92'],['PJ72010', 'WORD',  'FLUIDS', 
'7.95']]

def isAlpha(temp):
   for i in temp:
      if i>='0' and i<='9':
         return 0
   return 1


isAlpha("abul")
anser_list=[]
for  i in nested_list:
   nested_list=[]
   temp=""
   for j in i:
      if isAlpha(j)==1:
         if len(temp)>0:
            temp+=" "
         temp+=j
      else:
         if len(temp)>0:
            nested_list.append(temp)
            temp=""
         nested_list.append(j)
   if len(temp)>0:
      nested_list.append(temp)
   anser_list.append(nested_list)

for  i in anser_list:
   print(i)
```

Output will be:

```
['72010', 'PHARMACY -IV FLUIDS', '7.95']
['TOTAL HOSPITAL CHARGES', '6,720.92']
['PJ72010', 'WORD FLUIDS', '7.95']
```

Comment: If my comment is helpful, then please upvote it. Thanks